# How can I improve a program that calculates a sum from receipt totals from a text file?

Tags: java, file, text, java.util.scanner, java-io

I have this program below so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class Receipts 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        File file = new File("receipt.txt");
        PrintWriter exit = new PrintWriter(
                           new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter(file, true)));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);


        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello. What would you like to do today?", "Receipts", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"See my total", "Add a receipt"}, "default");


        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0:  // see my total
            {
                double total = scan.nextDouble();
                String StrTotal = format.format(total); 

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total so far is $" + StrTotal + ".");
            }

            case 1:  // add a receipt
            {
                double receipt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount."));
                double addTotal = scan.nextDouble();
                exit.print(format.format(receipt + addTotal));


                exit.close();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount has been added.");
            }

            default:
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input your selection.");
                exit.close();
                break;
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

In the text file `receipt.txt`, I have a single number (like: "**0.00**") that the program is supposed to fetch then use it for calculations.

1. There's an error stating:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
        at Receipts.main(Receipts.java:26)
```

How can I fix this?

2. Is there a way to make it so that the `FileWriter` removes the sum from the text file and adds it to the user's input, then prints it again in the file to use again? Or any better way to calculate a sum repetively?

Comment: You are attempting to both write to and read from the same file. There are ways to do that, but for your use case with a scanner, do the scanning first, close the scanner, and then do the writing/updating as needed. As for "Or any better way to calculate a sum repetively?", just keep a class variable with the running total, or use a list if you want to store multiple values?

Comment: Note that an `InputMismatchException` is caused by this line `scan.nextDouble();` where your scanner is trying to read something that is not a double. Check the contents of the `receipt.txt` to see what is first, because your code expects a double value, not a string that it is likely returning. You need to advance past any strings/text in the file before reading the double values. Or you need to read the entire line, and split it up and extract the number text and cast it to a double